# How to show current row grouping value in multi column rdlc report

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I am creating a three column rdlc report where I need to show current running value of a field on which rows are grouped. This running value I need to display in header of report. So whenever the field value changes it must reflect in the header.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/sazx2o31z6xui0u/Capture.PNG?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m8ekpffhnf7veiq/Capture1.PNG?dl=0

In above two images notice that as the type of therapy changed for clients, the name of current therapy is changed in the header. These all clients are grouped on therapy name.

This is the template what I got. I need to create rdlc reports like this but I dont know how to access current row grouping value in report header. Though I have created three column layout but still not able to access this grouping value in header.

Any solution?